# How to set a revision number for svn external?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

So I have this file Mobile.framework and if I do a `svn propedit` i get

```
svn propedit svn:externals
```

It brings up

```
Mobile.embeddedframework  svn+ssh://../Mobile.embeddedframework
```

This is pointed to the head.

I want to edit this and set it to -r1209. Whats the correct way to set it to a revision?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the [SVN manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html):

`Mobile.framework  svn+ssh://../Mobile.embeddedframework@100` - note the `@100`.

(or)

```
svn propedit svn:externals .
```

can help you edit it.

Comment: svn: Setting property on non-local target 'svn+ssh://../Mobile.framework' needs a base revision

Answer (score 2):

```
svn propset svn:externals \
Mobile.framework  svn+ssh://../Mobile.embeddedframework@1024
```

1024 is arbitrary :) replace it with the revision number you want to use

**EDIT**
Then for 100 you use

```
svn propset svn:externals \
Mobile.framework  svn+ssh://../Mobile.embeddedframework@100
```

**EDIT AGAIN*** Oh yes, I forgot the target

```
svn propset . svn:externals \
Mobile.framework  svn+ssh://../Mobile.embeddedframework@100
```

Note, that there is a dot in the command.

Comment: svn: Setting property on non-local target 'svn+ssh://../Mobile.framework' needs a base revision

Comment: Okay, I set that and commited the change. Now if I svn up,.. svn: warning: URL 'svn+ssh://../Mobile.embeddedframework@1209' at revision 1211

Comment: Then you can delete all the contents of the Movile.framework folder and update again or execute the following command in the folder with the external definition: `svn update -r1209 Mobile.framework`

Comment: "Because the `svn:externals` property has a multiline value, we strongly recommend that you use `svn propedit` instead of `svn propset`." - This is from the manual and relevant as soon as you have more than one external per directory. I recommend getting used to it and use it all times for `svn:externals`.