# Building a binary from a given artifact version in SVN

Tags: svn, clearcase

I have used ClearCase for source code control. In it only one VOB was maintained for a project.

If there was any custom development then a new branch will be created. In each folder there was a config file for each folders and there CM can specify which version of an artifact needs to be checked out. So if type `ls` then it will print the file with particular version as given in config although the LATEST version is something else.

In this way CM can build a custom project for a given customer from the same source.
I think this is a standard way of building jar / war from source by picking a particular version.

How to achieve the same functionality in SVN?

Answer (score 2):

You could check out the **[svn external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html)**, which can [reference a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1355956/6309) or another repo, [at a given revision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12699018/6309).

That way, different folders of an SVN repo can reference the same file/folder at different revision.

Comment: This will give you what you asked for, but such things are a pain to maintain. I'd take a moment to consider alternatives, since SVN and other systems were specifically designed to avoid the need to juggle versions of thousands of individual files on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: @Ben I agree, this doesn't scale well. Let's wait for the OP's feedback.

Comment: Thank you @VonC. We are developing product and using SVN for source code control. I have experience in building custom product in Rational ClearCase environment so was thinking if SVN will also solve my purpose of creating custom builds are we should migrate to CC or some SCM tool

Comment: @VonC waiting for your response. I want to maintain a single point of source and want custom implementation for various client using branch and labels like in CC and create various versions of product using build file and config file where config file will have path for right version of source file required for a specific client. Please let me know if I am not clear about my question?

Comment: @Shailesh I have more experience with Git, where I manage submodules (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30773352/6309)